# Are there any alternatives to drupal_add_js()?

Tags: 7, javascript

Are there any alternatives to `drupal_add_js()` that permit to write inline JavaScript code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) allows inline code:

```
drupal_add_js($your_js, 'inline'):
```

You should however not rely on it too much. JS can be better cached by the browser (and aggregated with other JS) if delivered in a separate file.

Comment: Yes, but I wandering if there is any other method beside `drupal_add_js($your_js, 'inline');` or js file to insert js code in theme output function of a module for instance, something like js script tag, embedded in HTML output. Is this a good practice ?

Comment: In Drupal 7, you can also use #attached to "attach" CSS and JS files to a form for example. The following presentation seems to have a lot of information that you want to check out: http://www.slideshare.net/katbailey/javascript-in-drupal-7-what-developers-need-to-know. Always use #attached (doesn't work for inline JS, I think) or drupal_add_js(). That will result in <script> tags in the end, but in the correct order, place and aggregated according to the configuration.

Comment: Actually, you can even use inline JS with #attached, as explained in that presentation.